# Building C++ program with Blas/Lapack libraries

Tags: c++, lapack, blas

I'm struggling to build with Visual Studio 2019 a C++ application that needs BLAS/LAPACK libraries.

When building the problem, link.exe produces these errors:

```
l1tf.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol dgbsv_
l1tf.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol dpbtrs_
l1tf.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol dgbtrf_
l1tf.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol dpbtrf_
...
```

So, I downloaded the Windows versions of BLAS and LAPACK libraries and added these parameters to the linker:

> /LIBPATH:D:\my_program\libs
>   LAPACK.lib BLAS.lib

But I still get the same errors… I investigated the content of LAPACK.lib with dumpbins and the missing symbols (dgbsv, etc) can be found.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Show some [mre] in your question and give an example of compile command

Comment: The real example is a bit complicated, I try to build a python extension in C++ that ou can find here (https://github.com/joshloyal/L1-Trend-Filtering). But the error is not related to python, it's the linker that complains. There must be something wrong with the libs I try to link with, but building BLAS and LAPACK from scratch looks quite complicated (it requires a Fortan compiler).

Comment: I created a fresh VS project with a file that calls a function from the BLAS and I could build it for x86 but not for x64… It seems that the libraries have been compiled in 32-bit. But I can't find the right libraries on the net.